# Backbone router with infinite optional parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, backbone-routing

I am creating a single-page application. Initially, I am using the URL "/stop/stop_id", which then loads content using stop_id.

I would like to support multiple stops. I imagine an URL like "/stop/stop_id/stop/stop_id", where it can grow by potentially endless amounts of "/stop/stop_id".

Can this reasonably be done with the Backbone router, and if so, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can use route `/stop/*ids` and then split ids into array by `/` character. So you get url `/stop/id1/id2/id3`.

Comment: I ended up with
'  routes:
    "stops/*ids": "loadStops"'
and
'  loadStop: (ids) ->
    stopIds = ids.split "/"'

Perfect, cheers!